# Convert this linq code to expression

Tags: c#, linq

Can an expert in C# helps me to convert this linq code into Expression trees ?

```
var settingViewModels = from l in settingsByEnvironment["Localhost"]
                                from d in settingsByEnvironment["Dev"]
                                from p in settingsByEnvironment["Prod"]
                                where l.Key == d.Key && p.Key == d.Key
                                select new MyKeyValue
                                {
                                    Key = p.Key,
                                    LocalhostValue = l.Value,
                                    DevValue = d.Value,
                                    ProdValue = p.Value
                                };
```

Thanks !

Comment: try using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var settingViewModels = from l in settingsByEnvironment["Localhost"].AsQueryable()
                        from d in settingsByEnvironment["Dev"].AsQueryable()
                        from p in settingsByEnvironment["Prod"].AsQueryable()
                        where l.Key == d.Key && p.Key == d.Key
                        select new MyKeyValue
                        {
                            Key = p.Key,
                            LocalhostValue = l.Value,
                            DevValue = d.Value,
                            ProdValue = p.Value
                        };

var expression = settingsViewModels.Expression;
```

Comment: there're no Expression property on my settingsViewModels variable. What should I reference?